# Android: How to wrap content of a LinearLayout inside a TableRow vertically?

Tags: android

I'm trying to add a list of tags (basically just TextViews with a background and a border applied) to a TableRow programmatically.

I've added a LinearLayout to the TableRow to use as the container. Unfortunately I don't seem to be able to make the layout wrap vertically - i.e. if there are lots of tags to add, the list just goes horizontally off the screen.

How can I add a list of TextView items to a LinearLayout inside a TableRow? Here's my layout:

```
    ...
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/LabelTheme"
            android:text="@string/interests" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/eventInterestContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" />

    </TableRow>
    ...
```

Note: I added a LinearLayout because otherwise each tag's width was the width of the cell, and instead I want the width to wrap_content. Perhaps this isn't necessary though?

Comment: try to change your linear layout orientation to vertical

Comment: I want it to put as many tags on one line horizontally as possible, but then wrap onto the line below when necessary. If I change the orientation, they're all placed vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the orientation value of your LinearLayout to "vertical".

If you want to "put as many tags on one line horizontally as possible, but then wrap onto the line below when necessary", you could have a series of "horizontal" linear layouts and add your content to the next/consecutive linear layout once the content for the proceeding one is greater than your screen width

Comment: That seems like a lot of work. isn't there a way of making android to that for me?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html might suit your problem better than the linear layout?  If not, then as far as I know there would not be a simple way of getting Android to do this for you without implementing multiple linear layouts